# Can Jenkinsfile parameters be combined with pipelineJob parameters?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

Suppose there is a scripted *Jenkinsfile* that is used by couple of groovy `pipelineJob('my-job'){}` files. Each *pipelineJob* deploys to a new environment, therefore there are common jobs parameters and specific per environment parameters like ENV = dev/qa/prod.

*Jenkinsfile* example below. In this case when we run the Build with Parameters job from the Jenkins UI we should choose the ENV.

```
properties([
  parameters([
    booleanParam(name: 'enableIndexingScript', defaultValue: false),
    choice(name: 'ENV', choices: ['dev', 'qa', 'prod'])
  ])
])

switch(environment) {
    case "dev":
        clusterName = 'dev-cluster'
        cloudName = 'dev'
        break
    case "qa":
        clusterName = 'qa-cluster'
        cloudName = 'qa'
        break
    case "prod":
        clusterName = 'prod-cluster'
        cloudName = 'prod'
        notifyMe = true
        break
    default:
        println("Check env!")
        break
}
```

What we can do is to move `choice()` part from Jenkinsfile to pipelineJob groovy file. In result we have 3 groovy definitions, one per environment: *deploy-to-dev.groovy, deploy-to-qa.groovy, deploy-to-prod.groovy* and better/granular control over Jenkins jobs.

```
pipelineJob('deploy-to-dev') {
    parameters {
        choiceParam('ENV', ['dev'])
    }
---
pipelineJob('deploy-to-qa') {
    parameters {
        choiceParam('ENV', ['qa'])
    }
---
pipelineJob('deploy-to-prod') {
    parameters {
        choiceParam('ENV', ['prod'])
    }
```

**Goal:** Reduce human interaction and errors when choosing specific environment parameters by keeping common jobs parameters in the *Jenkinsfile* and specific parameters in the *pieplineJob* definition file.

From what I see parameters defined in the `Jenkinsfile` take precedence over parameters defined in `pipelineJob`.

Is there a solution to avoid this precedence behaviour and combine all parameters?